# A game of red and black

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, board-games

Two players, red and black, play a game. The outcome is as follows:

> CCCBBABCDFBBDDE

Who won the game, and what game were they playing?

HINT:

> The outcome also includes a string of numbers, but they do not give any more information than the first string.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The game is

> Connect Four

and the result is

> a first-player win, running down a diagonal in columns B-E.
>
>  [image]

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Checkmark incoming!